# Make bullets fly out of ship correctly using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to make a game similar to the classic, Asteroid, and I have a problem trying to make the bullets shoot in the correct direction. My code can be found here:

https://jsfiddle.net/studentlearning110/c2quhdad/2/

```
var vectorX = BULLET_SPEED * (Math.cos(angle));
var vectorY = BULLET_SPEED * (Math.sin(angle));
bullet.style.top = parseInt(arrow.style.top) + 10 + bulletHeight + 'px';
bullet.style.left = parseInt(arrow.style.left) + 10 + bulletWidth + 'px';
```

I believe the problem lies within the angleDeg variable, but I cannot get the angle to stay consistent with the mouse pointer.

For some reason, the code does not run on jsfiddle, but works on my local browser.

I have been learning JS for about 2 months now, so please let me know if I am doing anything that is absolutely wrong. Thanks!

Comment: Your jsfiddle doesn't have jquery loaded.  In jsfiddle, loading jquery is a an option from the pull down menus.  The script uses `$(document)`, and  that's probably jQuery as it uses that a lot and plain javascript doesn't have a function called `$`.  Once jQuery is loaded, I never could get any shots to fire from the large triangular shaped ship.

Comment: You aren't converting from degrees to radians in your fire function. I suggest avoid degrees all together. Radians are much more simple, and there isn't any converting back and forth because all of the functions use radians